# Setting the layout of ServiceStack Razor views on per-customer basis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, servicestack

I am working on a ServiceStack-based web application that will be used by multiple clients. There is a default layout/design that will be used in the absence of a client-specific one. So I was hoping to take advantage of the support for cascading layout templates available now in ServiceStack Razor but am having no luck making it work.

Here is roughly how I have structured the views in my project:

```
\
    _ViewStart.cshtml
    DefaultLayout.cshtml
    SomeSharedContentPage.cshtml
    \Views
        SomeSharedViewPage.cshtml
        \ClientA
            LayoutA.cshtml
            StylesA.css
        \ClientB
            LayoutB.cshtml
            StylesB.css
```

The logic in _*ViewStart.cshtml* checks the identity of the logged-in user and sets the appropriate layout kind of like this (in a simplified form):

```
if (user.Client.ID == CLIENT_A_ID)
    Layout = "~/Views/ClientA/LayoutA.cshtml";
else
    Layout = "~/Views/ClientB/LayoutB.cshtml";
```

In turn, client-specific **LayoutA** and **LayoutB** both use the shared basic design/layout defined in *DefaultLayout.cshtml* by including the following at the top:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/DefaultLayout.cshtml";
}
```

I was hoping to achieve a cascading nested layout effect whereby both **SomeSharedViewPage.cshtml** and **SomeSharedContentPage.cshtml** are displayed with the final layout comprising both the default and custom elements.

Unfortunately it doesn't work even when I hard-code one of the layouts in the view, nor when I explicitly specify the path of the layout page (e.g. `Layout="~/Views/ClientA/LayoutA.cshtml"` instead of `Layout="LayoutA"`).

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I got the top-level shared layout to work by renaming `DefaultLayout.cshtml` to `_Layout.cshtml` but client-specific layouts `LayoutA` and `LayoutB` are still not not being applied, so obviously SS Razor now simply falls back to `_Layout.cshtml` by convention.

I know that support for [cascading nested layouts was recently added to ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/711), so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the testing I've done, I don't think ServiceStack Razor supports _ViewStart.cshtml. However, you should be able to dynamically change the Layout via code using other methods. For example, you could set it up like this:

Default.cshtml

```
<h2>Default</h2>
```

Views\_Layout.cshtml (the default for ServiceStack Razor)

```
@{
    if (user.Client.ID == CLIENT_A_ID)
        Layout = "_Layout2";
    else
        Layout = "_Layout3";
}
```

Views\_Layout2.cshtml

```
<h1>Layout2</h1>
@RenderBody()
```

Views\_Layout3.cshtml

```
<h1>Layout3</h1>
@RenderBody()
```

You should also be able to use \Views\ClientA\ALayout.cshtml but you will have to make sure all the layout files use a unique name like ALayout.cshtml and BLayout.cshtml.